# Is there any method to choose the value of each pixel according to land cover

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, erdas-imagine

I have 2 images; one is land cover image (imgA) and monthly mean temperature image (imgB). I'd like to choose value of each pixel from imgB corresponding to imgA. 
WhaT I expected is each pixel of certain land cover type should have different values in different area. I tried it using zonal statistic in ArcGIS and ERDAS. But zonal statistic give me only one value of each land cover (not in each pixel value). I'd like to keep all original pixel values of imgB according to each land cover. How can I do this using ArcGIS or ERDAS?

Comment: ii'm not sure to understand, but maybe you can use zonal histogram.

Comment: It is unclear what it would mean to "choose value of each pixel from [one image] corresponding to [another image]." What exactly would the output look like? Please edit your question to clarify this.  Perhaps you could supply a tiny example?

Comment: Have you looked into using Con http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000

Answer (score 1):

Using [Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000) in ArcGIS should accomplish this task.  Create a new field in your land cover raster and assign indicator numbers to each type (ie, Industrial = 100, Forest = 200, etc).  Then add the two raster layers.  Your output will have a 3-digit field where the first digit will indicate land cover and the second and third digits will represent the mean temp.

Comment: Let's hope mean temperatures are not negative!

Comment: yes, this is a pretty basic and rigid technique, but I've used it successfully with land cover data before.

Comment: The LC image has originally indicator field named "Value". It has value Forest, desert 2 etc. Do I need to create another field? In raster calculator, what kind of expression should I run? Thank uou

Comment: I have added the field and assigned numbers to them like forest 1, desert 2 etc. Then added 2 raster images (LC and temp) into raster calculator and then no idea how to create output image which include pixel values of temperature img and LC number.

Comment: You need to add the two rasters to get an output raster with the combined values.  See: [Building Expressions with Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000zn000000)

Comment: I have found that it is easy in ERDAS using "Either if" conditional statement of model maker. Hope this helps.